# Is it possible to access external bot from Microsoft teams channel?

Tags: botframework, microsoft-teams

I want to access to external bot from Microsoft teams. What is the best way accomplish this?

```
MS Teams channel <-> MS Bot <->  External Bot API
```

the above flow is only possible solution or there is any better way to accomplish this?

Comment: When you say "External Bot API" are you referring to Bots build wihtout using Microsoft Bot Framework? If yes, then only solution is having MS bot calling extenal Bot's rest APIs.

Comment: In addition: if you have a bot on some-other-framework, then its simple to add a simple adapter based on the Microsoft Bot Framework to allow that bot to be surfaced in Teams.